# What can be used with MySQL instead of EntityFunctions.DiffMilliseconds

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-order-by

I have to OrderBy and Filter by TotalTime - computed value between Finish and Start. Previously, with MS SQL I was using

```
records = records.OrderByDescending(o =>  (o.LastRunStart != null) ? EntityFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(o.LastRunFinish ?? DateTime.UtcNow, (DateTime)o.LastRunStart) : 0);
```

But with MySql it is not working. Is there any useful method in EF for MySql that can by used in select?

Comment: what you mean `MySql it is not working.` ?? any error?

Comment: "FUNCTION <database name>.DiffMilliseconds does not exis"t or other DiffDays or like this

Comment: You can always create a `list<record>` from your mySql and then make the sort there.

Comment: I know, but it's better to filter, to order, and apply paging on sql server and get 10 results / otherwise sort list will sort list on the app server in memory

Comment: maybe check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752939/entityfunctions-support-in-mysql

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we have some clue of what you are working with.

Comment: May be view can be a good solution?